# How to display content when there are no anchor tags in url

Tags: javascript, html, css, target

I would like to display a block of code when there are no anchors in the url. I have a few blocks set up to display when the anchor selects them, but I want to set up a default for when nothing is called.

```
<div>
    <!-- default content -->
</div>
<div id="a">
    <!--displays on example.com/#a-->
</div>
```

The css styling for #a

```
#a:target {display:block;}
#a {display:none;}
```

I could use javascript and subscript the url, and run a few conditionals but that would be a rather jimmy-rigged solution.

Comment: Why not use javascript ?

Answer (score 1):

In `DOMContentLoaded` event, use `window.location.hash` to check if there is any hash in the URL, if not display the default.

Docs:

- [`DOMContentLoaded` - Event reference | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)
- [`Window.location` - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)